# Регулярное выражение, чтобы получить содержимое между тегами

Tags: регулярные-выражения

**Задача**: Получить содержимое между тегами
**Пример**: `<div class='ClassName'><!-- содержимое --> </div>`
**Инструмент**: Использование можно только регулярные выражения, верстка содержит ошибки и другие способы работают не верно.

**Моя реализация**:

```
<div class='ClassName'>(.+)</div>     // Не работает, если есть переноси строк
<div class='ClassName'>([^<]+)</div>  // Такой вариант годился, если можно было
                                      // не набор символов, а целый фрагмент "</div>"
```

Comment: `Такой вариант годился, если можно было не набор символов, а целый фрагмент "</div>"` - не понял немного. поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: А почему бы не воспользоваться каким-нибудь hmtl парсером, мне кажется, если у вас будут вложенные теги, то там любая регулярка выдаст ошибку.

Comment: @Andrei Khotko,  имеется введу, что приведеный мной пример `([^<]+)` выводи контент до тех пор, пока не встретит сивмол '<'. Если сделать так `([^<\/div>]+)`, это пример выведет все, до первого символа <, /, d, i, v.... А я хотел, чтобы он вывел все до фрагмента "</div>"

Comment: @Drakonoved, это немного не то =(

Comment: @Shiki, там не валидная верстка. Парсеры не работают эффективно. Я видел регулярку, какая выполняла мою текущую задачу, но не могу найти

Comment: Укажите _конкретный_ движок регулярных выражений (язык программирования хотя бы). Потому что в разных движках разные возможности. Чтобы точка в вашей первой регулярке матчила переносы строк, см. [Модификаторы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения#Модификаторы), а именно `s`.

Comment: Многие html-парсеры прекрасно работают с некорректной вёрсткой. Если укажете язык программирования, то, возможно, найдётся такой парсер.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, php

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, меня больше интересует регулярное выражение. Видел такой пример, но не могу найти. Интересно

Comment: Вообще, использование модификатора решает вашу проблему. Но можно использовать [Просмотр вперёд и назад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения#Просмотр_вперёд_и_назад)

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, спасибо Вам, почитаю больше про это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такое регулярное выражение:

```
(?:<div class='ClassName'>)(?:\s*)([\S\s]*)(?:<\/div>)
```

Вот [пример использования](https://regex101.com/r/lXBoV1/1)

Небольшое пояснение:

- `?:` - обозначает группу, которая не будет включаться в группу совпадения
  (match group)
- `(?:\s*)` - не включаем лишние пробелы в начале содержимого тега (при необходимости, можно убрать)
- `([\S\s]*)` - любой символ, включая и пробельные символы (в том
  числе, и перенос строк)